# Table - Update cell on current row

Tags: html, jquery, html-table

I am trying to update cell 1 of current row with the value from Select.
I know if I change the `$(this).closest('tr')` with a number, it will affect that row, but it would not trigger for that current row.

```js
function currentrow(number) {
  document.getElementById('mytable').rows[$(this).closest('tr')].cells[1].innerHTML = number;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="column()" onchange="currentrow(this.value)">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" selected>3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="column()" onchange="currentrow(this.value)">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" selected>2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Figure it out.
```
function currentrow(select) {
    $(select).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").text(select.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following Answers Will help you

```js
function currentrow(element) {
  element.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = element.value;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
   <tr>
     <td>
       <select name="column()" onchange="currentrow(this)">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3" selected>3</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
       3
     </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <select name="column()" onchange="currentrow(this)">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2" selected>2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
       2
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Detail View**

Here I split above mentioned JS code into multiple line.

```js
function currentrow(element) {
  var selectedValue = element.value, // get selected value
    parentCell = element.parentNode, // get parent td element
    nextTargetCell = parentCell.nextElementSibling; // get next td element 
    
    // set next td element value with selected value 
    nextTargetCell.innerHTML = selectedValue; 
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
   <tr>
     <td>
       <select name="column()" onchange="currentrow(this)">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3" selected>3</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
       3
     </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <select name="column()" onchange="currentrow(this)">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2" selected>2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
       2
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```